# Background images in HTML but not CSS

Tags: css, image, background, sprite

Doing an online programming course and completely stuck on this bit. Have tried the same thing in Brackets / Atom / Sublime and all do the same thing. I can view an image no probs if it is called in src="" in html but trying to call it as a background image in CSS (either internally or externally) will always give alt text.

I've got copies of the image in all directories to help it locate it and have tried variations of ..//  \  " " '' etc.

Any help please! I can't move on until I solve this. This image shows the preview I'm getting: [image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vypMt.png)

Code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TEST CSS IMAGE LOCATOR</title>
  <style>
    #Maddie {
      height: 400px;
      width: 250px;
      background-image: url('bluebulletpoint.JPG');
      background: radial-gradient(circle, black, white);
    }
  </style>
</head <body>
<p>This is a picture of Maddie:</p>
<div id="Maddie">
  <img alt="missing picture" </div>
  <br><br>
  <div id="thisworks">
    <img src=bluebulletpoint.JPG>
  </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this:

```css
      background-image: url('bluebulletpoint.JPG');
      background: radial-gradient(circle, black, white);
```

The second line is CSS shorthand form which by rule overwrites the previous line completely. Move it to before the first line then you'll be fine. When you're done remove the `img` that says "missing picture", its not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

That is the maximum that I can offer:

```html
 <body>
        <p>This is a picture of Maddie:</p>
        <div style="background-image:url('bluebulletpoint.JPG'); background: radial-gradient(circle, black, white);height: 400px;
            width: 250px;" id="Maddie">
   
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <div id="thisworks">
              <img src=bluebulletpoint.JPG>
        </div>
    </body>
```

You don't need `<img>` in your div if It s on the background.

Comment: However, I have a new problem - now when I add co-odinates to try and set the start position of the image (e.g. url('images/IMG_6263.JPG') 0 0; ) the image disappears!

Comment: y need to add your coords to `div`, not to `image` and through css btw.(and upper than `background: radial-gradient(circle, black, white);` )

Comment: would you mind showing me how to do that? I can't work it out.